# Python interpolate problem, when looping through an inserting numbers to a list

Tags: python-3.x

**Task:**
A function that takes a list `lst` and an integer `n`.
If the difference between any two successive elements of the list is greater than `n`, then insert the average of the two elements as a new element between them. Repeat the process until the difference between all elements is less than `n`.

**Problem:**
Error when it needs to loop through the entire problem again.
Initial: `[9.5, 10.0]`
loop1: `[9.5, 9.75, 10.0]`
when debugging my loop2 skips the `9.625`
loop2: `[9.5, 9.75, 9.875, 10.0]` --incorrect

loop2:
`[9.5, 9.625, 9.75, 9.875, 10.0]` --correct

I've already tried the `sort()` function Which resulted in passing everything except the last test which has a list of un-ordered numbers. So I am rather using `insert()` in the code below:

**Code:**

```
def interpolate(lst, n):
    count=0
    if lst==[]:
        return []
    if len(lst)==1:
        return lst
    final_val=lst[-1]
    while (lst[1]-lst[0])>n:
        x=(lst[count+1]-lst[count])/2
        length=len(lst)
        if abs(lst[count]-lst[count+1])>n:
            y=lst[count]+x
            lst.insert(count+1,y)
        count+=1
    return lst

print(interpolate([], 0.5))  
#--lst = [] #--works
print(interpolate([9.0], 0.5))
#--lst = [9.0] #--works
print(interpolate([9.0, 10.0], 0.5))
#--lst = [9.0, 9.5, 10.0] #--works

print(interpolate([9.5, 10.0], 0.2))
#--lst = [9.5, 9.625, 9.75, 9.875, 10.0] #--ERROR
print(interpolate([-7.5, 10.66, 11.43], 5.3))
#--lst = [-7.5, -2.96, 1.58, 6.12, 10.66, 11.43] #--ERROR

print(interpolate([-4.0, -3.5, -3.0], 0.5))
#--lst = [-4.0, -3.5, -3.0]) #--works
print(interpolate([-4.0, -3.0, -3.5], 0.5))
#--lst = [-4.0, -3.5, -3.0, -3.5] #--works
```

Comment: Your example and the program description have a bunch of places where they don't match. `n` doesn't seem to ever be an integer, rather it's always less than 1 in your examples. And `7.5` isn't the average of `9.5` and `10.0`.

Comment: My mistake Blckknght, I corrected the question.

Comment: [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) style...

Comment: Please don't include the solution in the question. If the solution is contained in an answer, simply accept the answer (by clicking the check mark below the answer's score). If you ended up developing the answer yourself, add it as a new answer.

Comment: thanks glibdud, duly noted for next time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you dont reset your counter after each iteration(so program searches for list elements indexed higher than length of the list) i added one if statement in the end of your while loop

```
if (count>len(lst)-2):
            count=0
```

So it keeps everything in your style while fixing the issue

```
def interpolate(lst, n):
    count=0
    if lst==[]:
        return []
    if len(lst)==1:
        return lst
    final_val=lst[-1]

    while (lst[1]-lst[0])>n:
        x=(lst[count+1]-lst[count])/2
        length=len(lst)
        if abs(lst[count]-lst[count+1])>n:
            y=lst[count]+x
            lst.insert(count+1,y)
        count+=1
        if (count>len(lst)-2):
            count=0
    return lst
```

Comment: Hi @Yens if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.